# Calling functions from external python file throws 500 error

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to call a function from another python file. I have imported that function. When i call the function externally it works as expected.

But when i try to call the function before returning a render_template or a redirect , i get a 500 error. 
I know i am doing something wrong but i am not sure what. Any kind of help will be highly appreciated.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
from content_man import Content,Page_Content
from url_trigger import trigger

TEST_TOPIC = Content()
PAGE_TOPIC = Page_Content()

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/',methods=["GET","POST"])
def homepage():
     return render_template("main.html")

@app.route('/dashboard/',methods=["GET","POST"])
def dashboard():
    return render_template("dashboard.html", TEST_TOPIC=TEST_TOPIC)

@app.route('/test/', methods=["GET","POST"])
def test():
    if request.method == "POST":
        selected_list = request.form.getlist("to_run")
        print (selected_list)
        return redirect(url_for('trigger',selected_list=selected_list))
    else:
        return render_template("test.html", PAGE_TOPIC=PAGE_TOPIC)

@app.route('/trigger/', methods=["GET","POST"])
def trigger():
    data = request.args.getlist('selected_list')
    t = trigger(data)
    return "hey"



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

The error is in @app.route('/trigger/', methods=["GET","POST"]) where i am trying to call the function trigger.

My url_trigger python file contains the below simple definition:

```
def trigger(my_list=[], *args):
for i in my_list:
    print (i)
```

The HTML file for the page test is as:

```
<div class="container">
    <form method="post" action = "{{ url_for('test') }}">
        {% for row_index in range(PAGE_TOPIC['Critical BP']|count) %}
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label><input type="checkbox" name="to_run" value="{{      PAGE_TOPIC['Critical BP'][row_index] }}">{{ PAGE_TOPIC['Critical BP'][row_index] }}</label>
            </div>
         {% endfor %}
         <div>
             <label><input type="submit" /></label>
         </div>
     </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Show the full stack trace.

Comment: Hi Sergey, Below is the traceback: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Flask_Web/__init__.py", line 37, in trigger
    t = trigger(data)
TypeError: trigger() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Answer (score 1):

You import a function named `trigger`, but you also a define a function named `trigger` in the module where you do the import.  When `trigger` calls `trigger`, it is calling itself, and it accepts no arguments.  You need to rename one of the functions, or do the import as `import url_trigger` and then refer to the imported function as `url_trigger.trigger`.

Comment: That worked like a charm. Thank you so much for correcting the mistake.